android studio 8.2 and 8.7 does not show layout decorations
Layout Decorations is not found in the choices of View Options (as shown in the image) and therefore the layout is incomplete because the name of the application is not displayed and even the closing of the application window is no longer displayed as well when I run Android Device and I can no longer close the applications. please could you help me.
enter image description here
I tried to find Layout Decorations in Android Studio's picks in both version 8.2.2 and 8.7 but I couldn't find it.
